# How to add system DSN into odbc 32-bit using bat file?

Tags: sql-server, database, batch-file, cmd, odbc

I want to add ODBC data source automatically using batch file. I tried this command but not succeeded.

```
ODBCCONF.exe /a {CONFIGSYSDSN "SQL Native Client" "DSN=VizdomDatabaseSource|Description=VizdomDatabaseSource|SERVER=%Server%|Trusted_Connection=Yes|Database=eee"}
```

Comment: Next time please post your error message, instead of its not succeded. It could be many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this and run it with administrator rights

```
@echo off

set cn=%computername%
set host=%cn%\WINCC
ODBCCONF.EXE /a {CONFIGSYSDSN "SQL Native Client" "DSN=XY|Description=Descriptionname|SERVER=%host%|Trusted_Connection=Yes|Database=XY"}

echo  SYSTEM DSN created successfuly...
pause
@CLS
@Exit
```

Answer (score 3):

For 32-bit, execute the version in the `SYSWOW64` directory:

```
%windir%\syswow64\ODBCCONF.EXE /a {CONFIGSYSDSN "SQL Native Client" "DSN=VizdomDatabaseSource|Description=VizdomDatabaseSource|SERVER=%Server%|Trusted_Connection=Yes|Database=eee"}
```

Comment: It still gives error like this CONFIGSYSDSN : Unable to create the data source for the 'SQL Native Client' driver: Invalid keyword value pairs with error code -2147467259

Comment: Verify the `Server` environment variable is set correctly in your bat file before executing the commnad (e,g, `SET Server=YourServer`)`. As @Thomas mentioned, you also need to run as Administrator.

Comment: Now I add DSN successfully but its windows authentication. I want to add DSN with SQL Server authentication.I try this command but it's not working for me.







c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcconf.exe /a {CONFIGSYSDSN "SQL Native Client" "DSN=Testsource|Description=Testsource|SERVER=%server%|Trusted_Connection=No|Database=myDatabase|UID=sa|PWD=abc"}

Comment: @JamsheedSaeed, remove the UID and PWD keywords to create a DSN with SQL authentication. The user and password need to be specified by the application when using the DSN. SQL Server does not save those with the DSN for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
odbcconf configdsn "SQL Server" "DSN={NAME}|Description={DESCRIPTION}|Server={SERVER}|Trusted_Connection={Yes/No}|Database={DATABASE}"
```

This will work every time on Windows 10. The `Trusted_Connection` should be `Yes` for Windows authentication or `No` for SQL authentication. Everything else is rather straight forward. Do not add the `{}` brackets, that is where you insert your custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me

%windir%\syswow64\ODBCCONF.EXE configsysdsn "MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver" "DSN=testodbcconfMySQL;SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=3306;DATABASE=sys;UID=YYY;password=XXX"